# Can I take the 105 bus into Heathrow Central Bus Station?

Tags: uk, buses, lhr, tfl

I'm staying at the Premier Inn on Bath Road the night before my flight out of Heathrow T3. I don't really want to have to fork over £5 per person for the Hotel Hopper bus since I have a travelcard that covers all TfL buses.

According to Google, I should take the 111 bus from Oxford Avenue (Stop H) to get there, but since I have little trust for TfL services running as scheduled I would prefer to have a backup option in case the 111 doesn't show up in a timely fashion for whatever reason.

Apparently Oxford Avenue bus stop is also served by route 105, in theory doubling my chances of catching a bus without waiting too long at the bus stop, however according to TfL's website, despite the 105 leaving Heathrow Central Bus station to head off towards Greenford, when going towards the airport it terminates just outside at Nene Road. To me this doesn't make a whole heap of sense (since the bus has to go into the station to start the route out, why wouldn't it take passengers in?) so I was wondering if anybody had any first-hand experience that could confirm one way or another.

https://tfl.gov.uk/bus/route/105?direction=inbound

> [image: TfL's website shows route 105 starts at Heathrow]
>   TfL's website shows route 105 starts at Heathrow

https://tfl.gov.uk/bus/route/105?direction=outbound

> [image: but doesn't end there on the return journey]
>   But doesn't end there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 105 does in fact go to Heathrow Central bus station. As to why TfL's website incorrectly states otherwise I couldn't say

Answer (score 1):

I have used the 111 before and it is pretty reliable. Whenever I had to depend on it, it came on time but it’s still good to have a second option.

As to why the 105 doesn’t go to Heathrow Central Bus Station, I’m not sure but I can confirm it doesn’t go all the way. Maybe not enough bus stands or stops there/no place for it to park?

As to an alternative, you will need to do a bit of walking.

There are several options presented with Citymapper (iOS app).

Your one bus only choices:

- 12 minute walk to Harlington Corner Stop J and take the 140 or 285
- 12 minute walk to Hatton Road North Stop M and take the 285

(all of those buses go to Heathrow Central Bus Station)

Comment: Thanks @Daniil, that's pretty much what I suspected - that TfL has created a huge inconvenience that doesn't make any sense except that TfL like to do things that don't make sense.

I had considered walking to Harlington Corner, I don't mind but might have a tough time convincing the rest of my party, what with luggage and all

Comment: @elf337 yeah :) Any of those other routes should be fine though

Comment: Google Maps says you also have the option to use any of 81, 105, or 222 to Mondial Way (2 stops), where you can catch either of 140 or 285 (2 stops as well). You can also use 111 at both locations, but of course in that case you wouldn’t need to change.

Comment: @Daniil I'm grateful for your answer, but when it came to it I was able to take the 105 to the bus station. I wonder if perhaps it recently turned around before the station and then the route was extended, but only updated in one direction on the website, but that's just speculation on my part

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: This answer is posted after the OP has obtained first hand experience, simply for the sake of noting down what I have found in my brief research.

**Short version**: Yes, despite the TfL journey planner and route list saying 105 does not go into Heathrow for outbound (from Greenford, to Heathrow) trips, Bus 105 does go into Heathrow Central Bus station according to multiple sources, including some from TfL themselves.

---

## Document from TfL says yes

A [2011 public consultation from TfL on route 105](https://consultations.tfl.gov.uk/consultation-and-engagement/route-105/) included a map that clearly shows that outbound bus (from Greenford) goes all the way into Heathrow Central Bus station:

[image: Proposed changes to route 105 at Heathrow Airport, The Compass Centre. Original link https://consultations.tfl.gov.uk/consultation-and-engagement/route-105/user_uploads/105.jpg]

While the consultation result is not available on the page, given the route no longer serves The Compass Centre (see [the route of 105](https://tfl.gov.uk/bus/route/105/?direction=inbound)), the change is clearly introduced. There are no further consultation on route 105 as of the moment this answer is typed, and hence it is not possible for them to permanently alter the route between then (and in the near future).

## Data from TfL says yes

Someone has submitted a Freedom of Information (FoI) request to TfL, asking for [the times that 105 buses has departed each stop](https://tfl.gov.uk/corporate/transparency/freedom-of-information/foi-request-detail?referenceId=FOI-0653-1819) in first half of 2018.

The response from TfL contained a spreadsheet, in Direction 1 (from Greenford to Heathrow), Heathrow Central Bus Station is on the last column, with the times recorded usually a few minutes after the previous stop Nene Road (purportedly the terminal).

## Communications from TfL says yes

A [quick search on Twitter](https://twitter.com/search?q=105%20heathrow%20(from%3ATfLBusAlerts)&src=typed_query&f=live) suggests Heathrow-bound 105 buses do go into Heathrow. As the TfL Bus account do apologise if buses cannot get pass the tunnel into Heathrow (emphasis mine):

> Route 105 111 140 285 U3 X26 returned to line of route following East Ramp Heathrow protest (Nov 2016)
>   Heathrow Tunnel - Routes A10, U3, X26, 285, 105, 111, 140 are *terminating early* & unable to serve Heathrow due to a car stuck in the tunnel (Nov 2015)

## Bus fans says yes

Multiple videos and photos uploaded recently shows that the buses themselves are advertised to go to Heathrow Central.

Example video from BusesInLondon (June 2018): [Link](https://youtu.be/BCWnVtDg5Ts?t=28)
Example photo from  Adan Matthews (circa 2018/2019 by registration plate of the bus): [Link](https://www.londonbuses.co.uk/bus-photos/101-120/105_VH45274.jpg)
Example photo from hassaanhc (Mar 2019): [Link](https://www.flickr.com/photos/97628863@N06/47477844682)